# Temporary files after exporting video file with PHContentEditingOutput

Tags: ios, objective-c, photokit

I render a video file with `AVAssetExportSession`. I take an URL to render from `PHContentEditingOutput`. After using the editing output to modify the asset do I have to manually remove the file from the temp folder or Photos Framework does it for me?